# call method in compiler 0.8

Tags: solidity, truffle, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.6.x, solidity-0.7.x

how can i change this for older compiler versions like `0.4.24`?

`(bool success, ) = transaction.to.call{value: transaction.value}(transaction.data);`

and if you have time please explain to me the call method parameters here?
how is this line of code sending parameters to the `call` function?! why the `value` is sent in `{}` and `transaction.data` is sent in parenthesis?!
and why the `success` boolean inside parenthesis?! and why there is a comma there?!.
this `0.8` compiler is weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

A direct translation would be

```
bool success = transaction.to.call.value(transaction.value)(transaction.data);
```

- Since solc v0.7 `address.call{value: amount}()` indicates that `amount` ether will be sent with the call. Before that you had to use this syntax `address.call.value(amount)()`.
- `transaction.data` encodes the function and parameters to be executed. You can pass an empty `""` to call the fallback function.
- Sincd solc v0.5 `address.call()` returns a tuple `(bool, bytes memory)`. The `bool` parameters indicates if the call was successful or not, the second value is the output returned by the called function. By leaving out the second parameter it will be ignored `(bool success, )`.

Comment: thnx a lot brother